# Como pesquisar somente endereço pelo google maps?

Tags: javascript, html5, google-maps

Aqui tem exemplo em javascript:

```
    function initAutocomplete() {
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: {lat: -33.8688, lng: 151.2195},
        zoom: 13,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      });

      // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
      var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
      var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
      map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

      // Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.
      map.addListener('bounds_changed', function() {
        searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
      });

      var markers = [];
      // Listen for the event fired when the user selects a prediction and retrieve
      // more details for that place.
      searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {
        var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

        if (places.length == 0) {
          return;
        }

        // Clear out the old markers.
        markers.forEach(function(marker) {
          marker.setMap(null);
        });
        markers = [];

        // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        places.forEach(function(place) {
          var icon = {
            url: place.icon,
            size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
            origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
            anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
            scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
          };

          // Create a marker for each place.
          markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            icon: icon,
            title: place.name,
            position: place.geometry.location
          }));

          if (place.geometry.viewport) {
            // Only geocodes have viewport.
            bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
          } else {
            bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
          }
        });
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
      }

);
}
```

Aqui tem exemplo em html:

```
<input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search Box">
<div id="map"></div>
```

Esse código acima ele pesquisa em tudo. Como faço fazer ele pesquisar somente endereço ?

Comment: Você tem que usar o serviço de Geocode do Google Maps. Veja mais detalhes aqui: [Geocoding Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Use a opção `types` com um objeto Autocomplete

No seu código:

```
var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
```

Troque o objeto para `Autocomplete` e adicione a opção `types`, por exemplo:

```
var searchBox = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, {types: ['address']});
```

Pode ser que você tenha que fazer outras adaptações. Veja o exemplo [nessa página](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete) que usa o `Autocomplete` para saber se será necessário.

[Nessa página](https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types#table3) você encontra a especificação dos filtros que você pode usar com o `Autocomplete`.

Comment: Na linha: `searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function () {` não funciona, já botei debugger, e nada. E não aparece erro no console log.

Comment: O link com o exemplo que deixei é um exemplo do próprio Google. Tente rodar ele completamente do zero para identificar onde o seu JS está com problema.

Comment: Resolvido aqui. Obrigado